# Display domain url in custom Telescope theme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, telescope

I am customizing Telescope theme, and what I need is to display **domain url** from where the post is coming. It should be displayed in PostsItem.

Like it exist on Sidebar.io website, [this](http://content.screencast.com/users/shtefcs/folders/Jing/media/8b19100e-97b3-4cb4-b26d-ab94913572e9/2016-10-21_1216.png) part.

I asked the other day on Telescope slack channel and this is advice/instructions I got:

> Check in nova:posts/helpers there maybe a function to do that automatically. Else based on the string you get from the getDomain function, make it an array divided by /, and take the first argument which will be the domain

That should help I guess, I am just not experienced enough and couldn't make that work. So I still need help with this.

These links could be helpful too:
[utils.js](http://telescopejs.github.io/API-Docs/docs/telescope-lib_lib_utils.js.html) and [helpers.js](https://github.com/TelescopeJS/Telescope/blob/master/packages/nova-posts/lib/helpers.js)

I tried to add `<h3>{post.url}</h3>` inside file `CustomPostsItem.jsx` but I got full url, instead of just domain.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @ToonGijbels I just edited my question with more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got an answer on Telescope slack channel and it works.

```
{post.url ? <span className="post-url-domain">{Telescope.utils.getDomain(post.url)}</span> : null}
```